# Implementing a custom Hadoop key type and Value type

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, writable

I want to emit `key` and `value` as `custom datatype`.

whether I should implement `2 classes` for key and value?

one `KeyWritable implements WritableComparable` and

the other one

`ValueWritable implements Writable`.

Is it like that or one

`WritableComparable` is enough for `emiting custom key and value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use same class for your key and value, Then you need to write only one custom class which implements WritableComparable Interface.

A class which implements WritableComparable interface can be used for Key and Value. That means your new custom class will be Writable and Comparable also.

The super interfaces of WritableComparable are Writable and Comparable.

Please verify [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write KeyWritable separate if your key is not custom object and it's only text or string value.

Answer (score 0):

In Hadoop, every data type to be used as keys must implement `Writable` and `Comparable` interfaces or  more conveniently `WritableComparable`  interface, and every data type to be used as values must implement `Writable` interface.

If your custom key and value are of the same type, then you could write one custom data type which implements `WritableComparable` interface. If your custom key type differs from your custom value type, you will have to write two separate custom data types, where custom key class implements `WritableComparable` interface and custom value class implements `Writable` interface. Note that usually developers tend to use `WritableComparable` interface when they write custom data types since they can use interchangeably as custom keys and custom values. HTH